# valgrind showing invalid read error in std::map

Tags: c++, linux, stl, valgrind

I have a single threaded program which is showing invalid read error of size 4 when running with valgrind.

```
    void
 AccountStatus::transmitUpdate(int aiTuples, std::string& astrAliasPidf)
 {
  std::string lstrPidf;

  for (int i=0; i < TOTAL_TUPLE_COMBOS; i++)
  {
    if (_mSubList[i] != NULL)
    {
      GuidSubHandlerMap *subHandlerMap = _mSubList[i];

      if (this->getPidf (lstrPidf, i+1, aiTuples, astrAliasPidf, false) == -1)
        continue;

      ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG, ACCTPRES_DEBUG
        "transmitUpdate - created pidf for excludeMask [%X] with tuples [%X]\n", i+1, aiTuples));

      GuidSubHandlerMapIter iter;
      for (iter = subHandlerMap->begin(); iter != subHandlerMap->end(); iter++) //this line is shown as invalid read
      {
    subHandlerPtr lpHandler = iter->second;
    if (lpHandler)
    {
      lpHandler->queueNotify (CONTENT_TYPE, lstrPidf);
    }
  }
}
}
 }
```

The function which is showing in valgrind as having freed iterator is as follows,

```
    void
 AccountStatus::removeSubscription (const char *apcSubId, subHandlerPtr apHandler)
 {
  if (apcSubId && apHandler)
  {
    int excludeMask = apHandler->excludeMask();
    if (excludeMask != 0)
    {
      if (_mSubList[excludeMask-1] != NULL)
      {
        GuidSubHandlerMap *subHandlerMap = _mSubList[excludeMask-1];

        GuidSubHandlerMapIter iter = subHandlerMap->find (apcSubId);
        if (iter != subHandlerMap->end())
        {
          ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG, ACCTPRES_DEBUG
            "removeSubscription - [%s] mask [%X]\n", apcSubId, excludeMask));

          subHandlerMap->erase (iter); //this is where valgrind is showing memory being freed
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Valgrind output is as follows,

```
    ==9130== Invalid read of size 4
==9130==    at 0x9566CC: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==9130==    by 0x23A954CD: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >::operator++(int) (stl_tree.h:190)
==9130==    by 0x23AB4E01: ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::AccountStatus::transmitUpdate(int, std::string&) (accountStatus.cpp:518)

==9130==  Address 0x13604894 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 28 free'd
==9130==    at 0x400668A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==9130==    by 0x23A9647E: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:94)
==9130==    by 0x23A964B3: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >*) (stl_tree.h:362)
==9130==    by 0x23A96513: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > > >::destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >*) (stl_tree.h:392)
==9130==    by 0x23A97F67: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >) (stl_tree.h:1189)
==9130==    by 0x23A97FA1: std::map<std::string, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler> > >) (stl_map.h:446)
==9130==    by 0x23AB5515: ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::AccountStatus::removeSubscription(char const*, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ACCOUNT_PRESENCE::subHandler>) (accountStatus.cpp:314)
```

As I mentioned that program is single threaded, I don't know why this error. Can someone help me out with what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Seemingly 'something' with the container, Watson.  Please show all code that has to do with the container :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't show complete code so it's hard to say, but you should try to avoid modifying a container you are iterating over.

If you see [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) you will notice this line:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

So after you call `erase` the iterator(s) pointing to the erased element are no longer valid, which means you can no longer use e.g. `iter++`.

Comment: A valuable hint: "modifying a container you are iterating over"... OP carefully avoids showing us the line after the iteration :)

Comment: there are no erase modification in that loop and hence I had omitted that part. Have added it now.